# I have this error using python 3.8 from the interpreter >>> ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library

Tags: python

The code is of reading QR code in which the Import Error of zbar has occurred.I have attempted several changes in the installation of the module but I am not able to remove the error.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZCnH.png

Comment: Did you install `pyzbar` and how did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem you will need to install [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784) Install `vcredist_x64.exe` if using 64-bit Python, `vcredist_x86.exe` if using 32-bit Python. For more information check https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/#windows-error-message